# How to find nearest future date from now with specific weekday?

Tags: algorithm, date, datetime, dart, logic

I have an appointment management scenario in which I have a field List of `availableWeekDays` of a person on which weekdays they are available for booking. For example if they are available on monday I have a value in availableWeekDays list as 1.

I have currentDate stored in a `DateTime` variable using `DateTime.now()`.

What I have to do is first look if today's week day matches the availableWeekDay of person. If yes then bookingDate is valid else I have to look for nearest future date with weekday of person. I have tried following solution but it works for one week day as I'm using first index.

```
void main() {
  
  DateTime bookingDate = DateTime.now();
  int availableWeekDays = [1,4,7];
  
  getDate(){
    if(bookingDate.weekday == availableWeekDays[0]){
      print("Available on $bookingDate ");
    } else {
      bookingDate = bookingDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
      getDate();
    }
  }
  
  getDate();
  
}
```

I want to find the nearest future date among all weekdays present in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

````
DateTime findNearestWeekday(List<int> availableWeekdays) {
  assert(availableWeekdays.isNotEmpty);

  var date = DateTime.now();
  final weekday = date.weekday;

  for (var num in availableWeekdays) {
    if (num == date.weekday) {
      return date;
    } else if (date.weekday < num) {
      return date.add(Duration(days: num - weekday));
    }
  }

  /// I have assumed that you will always have a sorted list of available
  /// weekdays, in case you do not have a sorted list, either you can sort
  /// the list first or just use this line (instead of the last one),
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// import 'dart:math'; /// Add on Top of file.
  ///
  /// return date.add(Duration(days: 7 - weekday + availableWeekdays.reduce(min)))
  /// ```
  ///
  /// I will prefer to pre sort the array before storing it somewhere,
  /// because it will add an additional dependency dart:math


  return date.add(Duration(days: 7 - weekday + availableWeekdays[0]));
}
````

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution would be:

```dart
DateTime getDate() {
  var currentDay = bookingDate.weekday;
  var offset = (availableWeekDay - currentDay).remainder(7);
  return offset == 0 ? bookingDate : bookingDate.add(Duration(days: offset));
}
```

Do be aware that adding "days" (multiples of 24 hours) to a date may run into daylight savings issues if the time of the `bookingDate` is close to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to reassign the result to the variable. This works now.

```
void main() {
  
  DateTime bookingDate = DateTime.now();
  int availableWeekDay = 1;
  
  getDate(){
    if(bookingDate.weekday == availableWeekDay){
      print("Available on $bookingDate ");
    } else {
```

> ```
>       bookingDate = bookingDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
> ```

```
      getDate();
    }
  }
  
  getDate();
  
}
```